# Sum up all numbers between two numbers

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C# programming and trying to code a method that ask the user to give a start and an end integer number, then sum up all numbers from the start to the end and in case the given start number is greater than the end number, swap the values so that the start number becomes the end number and the end number gets the value of the start number.

This what I have done so far but I'm not getting the right answer when running the app:

```
private void SumNumbers()
{
    int startNumber, endNumber;
    Console.WriteLine("\nplease enter a start number: ");
    startNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("\nplease enter an end number: ");
    endNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int result = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<=startNumber; i=i+1)
    {
         result = result + i;
         Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("The sum of Numbers between " + startNumber + " and " + endNumber + " is: " + result.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'm getting this result: The sum of Numbers between 12 and 23 is: 78 when the result actually need to 210.

Comment: Excuse me. But how is this related to the actual language. This is just a simple algorithm which you cannot implement. This is not a general problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0;i<=startNumber;i=i+1)
```

You are iterating from `0 to startNumber`, when really you want to iterate like `startNumber to endNumber`.

Try

```
for (int i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; i = i+1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it worked however when I wrote 23 for the first number and 12 for the end number I got this result: 

please enter a start number: 
23

please enter an end number: 
12

The sum of Numbers between 23 and 12 is: 0

and the number didn't swapped

Comment: That makes sense, I don't see any code you have that attempts to swap the numbers in that scenario

Comment: Use `Math.Min(startNumber, endNumber)` and `Math.Max(startNumber, endNumber)` in the for loop instead of startNumber and endNumber, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working example.
I also added some logic to handle the checking of the input (whether it is correct or no) so the application doesn't break. This way the user experience is much better.

Here is the live working example: [code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sxnCsk)

```
private void SumNumbers()
{
    int startNumber, endNumber;
    Console.WriteLine("\nplease enter a start number: ");
    do
    {
        var input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Regex.IsMatch(input1, @"^\d+$"))
        {
            startNumber = Convert.ToInt32(input1); break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input provided is invalid. Please enter a correct number: ");
        }
    } while (true);

    Console.WriteLine("\nplease enter an end number: ");
    do
    {
        var input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Regex.IsMatch(input2, @"^\d+$"))
        {
            endNumber = Convert.ToInt32(input2); break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input provided is invalid. Please enter a correct number: ");
        }
    } while (true);

    int min = Math.Min(startNumber, endNumber);
    int max = Math.Max(startNumber, endNumber);
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
    {
        result = result + i;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The sum of Numbers between " + min + " and " + max + " is: " + result.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```